# header: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, g++

I have this cpp file:

```
//pkgnative_tries__native_NativeSystem.cpp
#include <pkgnative_tries__native_NativeSystem.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ClassName_MethodName
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring javaString)
{
    //Get the native string from javaString
    const char *nativeString = env->GetStringUTFChars(javaString, 0);
    cout << nativeString;

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(javaString, nativeString);
}
```

pkgnative_tries__native_NativeSystem.h:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class pkgnative_tries__native_NativeSystem */

#ifndef _Included_pkgnative_tries__native_NativeSystem
#define _Included_pkgnative_tries__native_NativeSystem
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     pkgnative_tries__native_NativeSystem
 * Method:    println
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_pkgnative_tries__1native_NativeSystem_println
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

The problem is that when i try compiling it to a DLL with `g++`, it says:

```
g++ -c -DBUILDING_EXAMPLE_DLL pkgnative_tries__native_NativeSystem.cpp

pkgnative_tries__native_NativeSystem.cpp:1:50: fatal error: pkgnative_tries__native_NativeSystem.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated
```

Does anyone know why? I'm sure that both files are in the same directory

Comment: Try `#include "pkgnative_tries__native_NativeSystem.h"`

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are using angle brackets in include (e.g. `#include <xyz>`) it does not look in the directory from where the include is done. Use double quotes instead, e.g. `#include "xyz"`.